# Google Analytics not showing active users

Tags: android, google-analytics

i gone through this documentation https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/ for the Analytics, but the active users cannot be shown but i get which Activity i'm in.

Here's the Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Now this is my MainActivity where i'm calling the tracker code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Tracker mTracker;
private final static String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // Obtain the shared Tracker instance.

    AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
    mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            sendAnalytics();
        }
    });

}

private void sendAnalytics() {
    String name = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    Log.i(TAG, "Setting screen name: " + name);
    mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
    Log.i(TAG,"Image Name: " + mTracker.toString());
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());



}
```

The Application class:

```
import android.app.Application;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;


public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {
private Tracker mTracker;


synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
    if (mTracker == null) {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this).setLocalDispatchPeriod(15);
        // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
        mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
    }
    return mTracker;
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Heading ##Make changes in you `AnalyticsApplication` as below..

```
public class AnalyticsApplication extends Application {

    private static Tracker mTracker;

    synchronized public Tracker getAnalyticsTracker() {
        if (mTracker == null) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker);
            mTracker.enableAutoActivityTracking(true);
            mTracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
        }
        return mTracker;
    }
}
```

---

Register your `AnalyticsApplication` In Manifest file.and also add following Service and Receiver in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:name=".AnalyticsApplication"
    .. >

    ...

    <!-- ANALYTICS -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    ...

</application>
```

---

Use Tracker as below in your `MainActivity`.

```
// ANALYTICS
AnalyticsApplication mApplication = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
mTracker = mApplication.getAnalyticsTracker();
mTracker.setScreenName("Main Activity");
mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

Comment: what is getAnalyticsTracker() ?

Comment: By mistake function name in `AnalyticsApplication`  written wrong.. check now.